# Accessing Object returned from factory AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angular-resource

I'm a beginner with AngularJS and I'm creating an application that retrieves data from an API.

The problem is: I don't know how to access the object that I'm returning or if there's a better way to do that.

**service.js**

```
app.factory('Service', ['$resource', '$q',
    function($resource, $q) {
        var City = $resource('http://localhost:8000/:action?:q_params', {
            action: 'api/city/',
            q_params: '@params',
        }, {
            get: {
                method: "GET",
                isArray : false,
                transformResponse: function(data, headers){
                    response = {}
                    response.data = data;
                    response.headers = headers();
                    return response;
                }
            }
        });

        return {
            citiesByCountry: function(country_id) {
                defer = $q.defer();
                var data = [];
                City.get({'country_id': country_id}).$promise.then(function(response) {
                    data.push.apply(data, JSON.parse(response.data));
                    defer.resolve(response);
                }).
                catch(function(response) {
                    alert(response.data.detail);
                    defer.reject(response);
                });
                return data;
            },
        };
    }]);
```

**control.js**

```
app.controller('Control', ['$scope', 'Service',
    function($scope, Service) {

        $scope.func = function() {
            var cities = Service.citiesByCountry('123');
            console.log(cities);
            console.log(cities.length);
            for (var item in cities) {
                console.log(item.name);
            }
        };

    }]);
```

When I call the function in the controller, the console.log prints:

> Array [ Object ]
>
> 0

The object is there, apparently, but I don't know how to access it.
I checked some questions and this one ([Accessing objects returned from a factory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30702965/accessing-objects-returned-from-a-factory)) was good but it didn't solve my problem, because I cannot access the object yet.

Comment: you want to access in the template?

Comment: No. I wanna access in the controller. @Sajeetharan

Comment: did my answer help